# Pulling data from melissa database, getting an TypeError: ("bad operand type for unary +: 'str'"

Tags: python, pandas

For this function:

```
def getData(key, full_name, address):
        url = 'https://personator.melissadata.net/v3/WEB/ContactVerify/doContactVerify?id=' + key +'&full=' 
        + full_name +'&a1=' + address
        xml = request.get(url)
        dom = parseString(xml.text)

        response = dom.getElementsByTagName('response')

        Gender = getElementValue(dom, 'Gender')
        DateOfBirth = getElementValue(dom, 'DateOfBirth')
        DateOfDeath = getElementValue(dom, 'DateOfDeath')
        EthnicCode = getElementValue(dom, 'EthnicCode')
        EthnicGroup = getElementValue(dom, 'EthnicGroup')
        Education = getElementValue(dom, 'Education')
        PoliticalParty = getElementValue(dom, 'PoliticalParty')
        MaritalStatus = getElementValue(dom, 'MaritalStatus')
        HouseholdSize = getElementValue(dom, 'HouseholdSize')
        ChildrenAgeRange = getElementValue(dom, 'ChildrenAgeRange')
        PresenceOfChildren = getElementValue(dom, 'PresenceOfChildren')
        PresenceOfSenior = getElementValue(dom, 'PresenceOfSenior')
        LengthOfResidence = getElementValue(dom, 'LengthOfResidence')
        OwnRent = getElementValue(dom, 'OwnRent')
        CreditCardUser = getElementValue(dom, 'CreditCardUser')
        Occupation = getElementValue(dom, 'Occupation')
        HouseholdIncome = getElementValue(dom, 'HouseholdIncome')

        return Gender
```

When I wrap this into a lambda:

```
df['Gender'] = df.apply(lambda row: getData(key, row['Full Name'], row['Address']), axis = 1)
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: ("bad operand type for unary +: 'str'", 'occurred at index 0')
```

Which occurs here:

```
   2         url = 'https://personator.melissadata.net/v3/WEB/ContactVerify/doContactVerify?id=' + key +'&full='
----> 3         + full_name +'&a1=' + address
```

How do I fix this issue?

For sake of completeness here is the entire code (without the Melissa key):

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parse,parseString
import xml.dom.minidom
import requests
import sys
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

key = ''

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

def getElementValue(p_dom,p_element):
    if len(p_dom.getElementsByTagName(p_element)) > 0:
       l_value=p_dom.getElementsByTagName(p_element)[0]
       return(l_value.firstChild.data)
    else:
       l_value='NaN'
       return(l_value)

def getData(key, full_name, address):
        url = 'https://personator.melissadata.net/v3/WEB/ContactVerify/doContactVerify?id=' + key +'&full=' 
        + full_name +'&a1=' + address
        xml = request.get(url)
        dom = parseString(xml.text)

        response = dom.getElementsByTagName('response')

        Gender = getElementValue(dom, 'Gender')
        DateOfBirth = getElementValue(dom, 'DateOfBirth')
        DateOfDeath = getElementValue(dom, 'DateOfDeath')
        EthnicCode = getElementValue(dom, 'EthnicCode')
        EthnicGroup = getElementValue(dom, 'EthnicGroup')
        Education = getElementValue(dom, 'Education')
        PoliticalParty = getElementValue(dom, 'PoliticalParty')
        MaritalStatus = getElementValue(dom, 'MaritalStatus')
        HouseholdSize = getElementValue(dom, 'HouseholdSize')
        ChildrenAgeRange = getElementValue(dom, 'ChildrenAgeRange')
        PresenceOfChildren = getElementValue(dom, 'PresenceOfChildren')
        PresenceOfSenior = getElementValue(dom, 'PresenceOfSenior')
        LengthOfResidence = getElementValue(dom, 'LengthOfResidence')
        OwnRent = getElementValue(dom, 'OwnRent')
        CreditCardUser = getElementValue(dom, 'CreditCardUser')
        Occupation = getElementValue(dom, 'Occupation')
        HouseholdIncome = getElementValue(dom, 'HouseholdIncome')

        return Gender

df['Gender'] = df.apply(lambda row: getData(key, row['Full Name'], row['Address']), axis = 1)
```

I have used the same approach for pulling data from zillow and mapquest with success but I cannot seem to get it to work for Melissa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
 url = 'https://personator.melissadata.net/v3/WEB/ContactVerify/doContactVerify?id=' + str(key) +'&full=' 
    + str(full_name) +'&a1=' + str(address)
```

Comment: Thanks that seemed to fix it, I converted those to stings already in the excel file, funny that I had to do it again...

Comment: I don't see how this fixes it.  The `+ str(full_name) ...` part is still on a separate line, which is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line:

```
+ full_name +'&a1=' + address
```

It seems like you expect it to be a continuation of the previous line, but it is not.